# .htaccess automatic redirect to one domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

What I try is to redirect (if you type it directly into the addressbar) to `https://example.com`
thus

```
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
example.com -> https://example.com
www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

I tried already (and other lots of other ways):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
www.example.com
```

will all redirect to  `https://example.com`

BUT `example.com` will not automatic redirect to `https://example.com`

How can i acomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR condition to match against both requests www or http and redirect it to https://non-www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will generate an error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` AFTER clearing browser cache

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it will ALSO generate an error on every way I approach my site: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` AFTER clearing browser cache/cookies , different browsers, etc.

Comment: Update: I'm using Cloudflare and maybe is THAT's is the problem(?)

Answer (score 0):

I think @starkeen s' way will work... but not when you're using Cloudflare!! The solution for people who using Cloudflare:

> Force HTTPS By default CloudFlare HTTPS doesn't force all the traffic
>   to HTTPS. To force HTTPS do the following:
>
> Go to your websites Click on the gear icon and select "Page rules"
>   Enter your website in the URL pattern input Toggle the "Always use
>   HTTPS" switch Click on "Add rule" at the bottom By doing this all the
>   traffic of your website will use HTTPS. When someone access your
>   website using HTTP, CloudFlare will redirect those request to HTTPS.

It worked for me.